# software for comparative debugging

Tags: gratis, linux, debugging

I have one executable (say a.out) and two sets of input data, say set1 and set2. I want to step through the runs simultaneously: i.e there will be two executables running, identical but different input. I want to able to debug the stage at which the result differs.

1. Do you know of a free tool that will let me do this?
2. Is there a way to step through the executables simultaneously in gdb or valgrind (without doing it manually?).

One option is to manually launch two sessions of gdb, dump a few variables (not exhaustive for a large code) and compare the datafiles. But this will be slow and hard. Looking through google, I found a way called comparative debugging although there may be other names I may not be aware of. Can I do Comparative debugging in recent versions of gdb or other tools? The only reference I found was from 1997. So help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not that I had seen something like that in 12 years of programming, but such a tool might be programming language and OS dependent. You might also want to tag this `gratis` and `linux`.

Comment: I know commercial debuggers such as Totalview and DDT have this feature. Unfortunately they are expensive.

Comment: For others finding this question: "RogueWave TotalView Individual Edition license for Mac OS X is available for US$849", Allinea DDT Workstation Parallel is available for a similar price (£715.00 = 829 €).

Comment: another tool is lgdb but it is also commercial and as far as I know, only for cray.

Comment: BTW, I [tried debugging 2 processes with WinDbg and failed miserably](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923117/is-multi-target-debugging-broken-in-windbg)

Comment: what do you mean by two processes? Do you mean two separate executables or two processes launched from one executable?

Comment: It doesn't matter. it could be two different applications, but it could be the same application twice with different parameters (that's what I've tried)